# How to keep my third column straight if my second one changes

Tags: bash, text-formatting

I have this output from a command.

```
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      A1
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      A2
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      A3
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      A4
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      A5
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  1      A6
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      B1
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      B2
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      B3
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      B4
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      B5
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      B6
```

So all my columns are straight. The only numbers that change are the ones from column 2 and 3. BUT, if one of those numbers change to a 2 decimal or more, my third columns misalign with the rest.

```
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      A1
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  15  0      A2
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      A3
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      A4
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      A5
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  347      A6
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      B1
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      B2
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      B3
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      B4
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      B5
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      B6
```

How can I keep my columns straight no matter how many decimals the numbers have?
This is how I would like it to be.

```
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      A1
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  15 0      A2
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      A3
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      A4
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      A5
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  347    A6
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      B1
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      B2
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      B3
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0  0      B4
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0  0      B5
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0  0      B6
```

Comment: So where is this output generated? That's the preferred place to correct the problem.

Comment: How will you use the data? Most tools won't care about this, so is it just so it looks good to humans or do you have some other final objective? Also, is this about a file or a stream of data printed to a terminal? Can you just pass the output or file through `column -t`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to modify the code that *generates* the data in such a way that the formatting generates aligned columns from the start, then you may use the `column` utility to post-process the output:

```bsh
some_command | column -t
```

Running the misaligned data in your question through `column -t` results in the following output:

```
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0   0    A1
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  15  0    A2
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0   0    A3
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0   0    A4
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0   0    A5
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0   347  A6
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0   0    B1
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0   0    B2
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0   0    B3
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0   0    B4
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0   0    B5
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0   0    B6
```

One possible downside with this is that `column -t` will shrink the minimal distance between columns to two spaces.

You may "fix" this by also output alignment characters (field delimiters) with the data, as in the misaligned data below:

```
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |A1         
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  |15  |0      |A2        
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |A3         
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |A4         
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |A5         
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  |0  |347      |A6       
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |B1         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |B2         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |B3         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |B4         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |B5         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  |0  |0      |B6
```

Using `column -t -s '|'` on this data would result in

```
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0    0     0          A1         
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0    15    0          A2        
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0    0     0          A3         
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0    0     0          A4         
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0    0     0          A5         
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0    0     347        A6       
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0    0     0          B1         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0    0     0          B2         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0    0     0          B3         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0    0     0          B4         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0    0     0          B5         
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0    0     0          B6
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this depends how you're generating the data. If you have a `printf` statement of some kind, for instance (whether in C or bash or other languages), you'd want to set the field widths.

E.g. in bash:

```
printf "%30s %3d %3d %5s" "CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0" 0 347 A6
```

would line things up, as long as numbers have at most 3 digits.

If you can't control the generation, a general way to line fields up is the command `column`. Pipe your command into `column -t` and it lines them up like this:

```
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0   0    A1
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  15  0    A2
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0   0    A3
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0   0    A4
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0   0    A5
CPU_SrcID#0_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0   347  A6
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0   0    B1
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0   0    B2
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0   0    B3
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#0_DIMM#0  0   0    B4
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#1_DIMM#0  0   0    B5
CPU_SrcID#1_MC#1_Chan#2_DIMM#0  0   0    B6
```

Note that this left-aligns the numbers, instead of right-aligning like `printf` would. Usually right-aligning numbers is better, so changing the generation is preferred. On some versions of `column` you can add an option `-R 2,3` to right-align those two columns, but your version might not have that option.

If you want more control over the format, you can pipe the output into a `while read` loop, and use `printf` to re-print the values, like this:

```
command | while read label num1 num2 code
do printf "%30s %3d %3d      %2s\n" "$label" "$num1" "$num2" "$code"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems that column -t works fine, but it only provides one space between each column, if you notice my desired output, i would like to keep those spaces between column 3 and column 4. Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: @JosueBaquerizo: Well, you can add an option `-o '    '` to separate *all* the columns with 4 (or however many) spaces. Alternatively, you could pipe into a bash `while read` loop and reprint them with printf.